# AngularJs with Docker throw Uncaught referenceError : Angular is not defined

Tags: node.js, angularjs, docker

I'm trying to containerized my app using docker and it throw Uncaught referenceError : Angular is not defined when I build using npm start

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM node:6.9.5-onbuild
COPY . .
RUN npm install -g bower
RUN npm install -g gulp-cli
RUN npm install

CMD ["gulp"]
```

Before it was throwing that it doesn't found bower-components folder, so i solved it using `bower install` to fix it, couldn't solve in docker.

When i execute my app with npm start without docker, it works just fine.

I'm using node 6.9.5 in my app.

Comment: Can you provide your package.json as well?

Answer (score 0):

Solved changing the node image from docker.

`alpine` image is more clean, I guess...

```
FROM node:6.9.5-alpine
COPY . .
RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```